# Getting specific value when using eloquent from Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I need to get specific values from the database with a leftjoin. The code I am using is as follow:

```php
public function commentList(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();

    $commentList = Comment::select(
        'projects_comments.id as comment_id',
        'u.name as user_name',
        'projects_comments.comment as comment',
        'projects_comments.created_at as created_at'
    );
    $commentList->leftjoin('users AS u', 'projects_comments.user_id', '=', 'u.id');

    if (!empty($inputs['project_ids'])) {
        $commentList->where(function ($query) use ($inputs) {
            foreach ($inputs['project_ids'] as $i) {
                $query->orWhere('projects_comments.project_id', $i);
            }
        });
    };

    $data = $commentList->get();

    return $data;
}
```

It works fine but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this using eloquent but I can't really understand how to write this for eloquent to work. I need to get all the comments from an array of project ids.

I have the following model for Comment:

```php
class Comment extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'projects_comments';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: "get all the comments from an array of project ids" do you mean something like `Comment::whereIn('project_id', $inputs['project_ids'])->get();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you want is to get Comments (with their users) that belongs to specific Projects provided by the user as an array of IDS

```php
Comment::whereIn('project_id', $inputs['project_ids'])->with('user')->get();
```

And if you only want the id and name of the user associated with the comment, pass the fields to the `with` function like so

```php
Comment::whereIn('project_id', $inputs['project_ids'])
       ->with('user:id,name')->get();
```

Comment: and in the user, how do you specify only some fields to be selected?

Comment: Pass the fields in the with property like so `with('user:id,name');`

Comment: no, it doesn't work, i get an error. I m using laravel 5.2 maybe it is the problem. I get this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user:id,name()

Comment: Aah yeah it's not available in 5.2, you can still create a custom relationship to load just what you want